# laravel- how to pass data to starter kit - dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

im new to laravel, im using laravel starter kit - i added "profile resource" simalar to "chirps" on
this bootcamp : [laravel bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/) with all relations 1:1 and so on.

but now im trying to pass the profile data to dashboard, fields like "about" "skills".
i have a working query, but i cant find way to use it in dashboard.

thiss the "profile-controler-index-method" its working but i only know how to use it with "index.vue" of "profile.vue" i couldnt use it with "dashboard.vue" because i just need the data not the whole vue script :

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Profile/Index', [  
        'Profile' => profile::with('user:id,name')->get(),
    ]);
}
```

and thiss my query :

```
DB::select('select * from profiles where user_id = 23');
```

after many loging trying to find the controller of dashboard or somthing helpfull, i found this file that gets loaded everytime i refresh "dashboard" "RouteServiceProvider"

```
  /**
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = '/dashboard';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, and other route configuration.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Log::info('infooo im here 1');
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

==============Edit :

i just found out that i can render any page i want in the index method.. whaaat..

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
        'Profile' => profile::with('user:id,name')->get(),
    ]);   
}
```

so if i can add some parameter to the index method .. i can render diffrent pages is this okey?
its so confusing these router and render terms..

Answer (score 0):

i think i solve it, but im not sure if thiss right .. if you have better way plz answer.

i redirect the route

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
//return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
return redirect('dashboards');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

to this route

```
Route::resource('dashboards', DashboardController::class)
->only(['index'])
->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

now i have "dashboards" instead of "dashboard" and i can pass through it but something seems not right ..